# UIButton to play when user touch drags their finger across the screen - Objective-C, IOS

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, piano

So I have a keyboard comprised of UIButtons that each contain an individual sound per button.
The sounds play when the user taps the button but I would like to know how I could get it to play when the user slide drags their touch on the screen like a piano glissando without lifting their finger off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a PanGestureRecognizer. For suppose if you arranged all your buttons in a TableView. Then you need to identify touched Cell from UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Add UIPanGestureRecognizer to your UITableView in Storyboard or by writing the following Code in your ViewDidLoad()

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panning:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:pRecognizer];
```

Then in panning Method

```
    -(void)panning:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {
       CGPoint panLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
       NSIndexPath indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:panLocation];

       //Get the cell from the table view
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       **call TouchupInside event of your Key here**
    }
```

So, now you can play Sound for all Keys when User panning on your Keys.

Comment: thank you for your reply. So when I create a tableview for all my buttons, would they all be individual tables or just one big tableview with several cells?

Comment: It's only One TableView with More Cells.

Comment: @ D. Venkata Naresh Would you be able to guide me a little on how I could now add Pan Gesture recognizer to my UITableView?

Comment: First of all add Pan Gesture to your Table View. Then Create an IBAction for that PanGesture. In that Find which Cell is Taped by Using the Statements in my Answer. Then Manually Call TouchupInside action of that Cell.

Comment: @ D. Venkata Naresh Thank you. How do I add a Pan Gesture to my UITable View? I have not yet experienced using Pan Gesture before sorry.

Comment: @Bor Ior See my Edited Answer